# Nodejs ffmpeg error: Output stream Closed

Tags: node.js, tensorflow, discord.js

I found this code on the internet for a speech recognition discord bot.
Repo link:https://github.com/d4sein/Speech-Recognition-Bot
but the problem is when I try to run it and give it an input it gives me back this error any way to resolve this?

```
Error: Output stream closed
    at Timeout._onTimeout (C:\Users\salos\OneDrive\Desktop\Speech-Recognition-Bot\node_modules\fluent-ffmpeg\lib\processor.js:491:25)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:557:17)
    at processTimers (node:internal/timers:500:7)
Emitted 'error' event on FfmpegCommand instance at:
    at emitEnd (C:\Users\salos\OneDrive\Desktop\Speech-Recognition-Bot\node_modules\fluent-ffmpeg\lib\processor.js:424:16)
    at Timeout._onTimeout (C:\Users\salos\OneDrive\Desktop\Speech-Recognition-Bot\node_modules\fluent-ffmpeg\lib\processor.js:491:17)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:557:17)
    at processTimers (node:internal/timers:500:7)
```